# Smoothing a sequence without using a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I am implementing a statistical method from an academic paper (see the end for a citation) in R. I think there's a way to do one of the steps without using a loop, but I'm having trouble deciding how to attack it.

This method operates on a data frame with three variables: x, n, and p. It can only operate if p[i] <= p[i+1] for all i. If a pair of points violates that, they are smoothed out by setting both p[i] and p[i+1] equal to their weighted average 
    (n[i]*p[i]+n[i+1]*p[i+1])/(n[i]+n[i+1])
This smoothing is iterated until the p_i are a nondecreasing sequence.

The problem with this smooth is that a) loops are bad form in R, and b) if there are multiple points in a row such that p_i > p_(i+1) >= p_(i+2), the method can fail to terminate or take a very long time to converge. For instance, if a sequence like so happens:

```
x  n  p
2  10 0.6
5  10 0.5
10 10 0.5
```

the smooth will set the first two values of p to 0.55, then the second two to 0.525, then set the first two to 0.5325, and so on and loop forever (or if I'm lucky reach the limit of significance in a bajillion iterations). There should be a mathematically equivalent but more efficient way to do this by identifying adjacent decreasing data points and averaging them as a group, but I'm not sure how to approach that in R.

If you need more background, the paper in question is [Martin A. Hamilton, Rosemarie C. Russo, Robert V. Thurston.
"Trimmed Spearman-Karber method for estimating median lethal concentrations in toxicity bioassays." Environ. Sci. Technol., 1977, 11 (7), pp 714–719](http://www.math.montana.edu/~jimrc/classes/stat524/notes/TrimmedSpearmanKarber.pdf). I'm referring to the "first step" section on page 716.

Comment: Is this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression the sort of thing you need? If so, maybe this is of value - http://statistics.ucla.edu/preprints/uclastat-preprint-2009:4

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing as Glen- is this equivalent to the pool-adjacent-violators algorithm in Robertson 1988?

Comment: It is. I suppose Hamilton & co. wouldn't know to call it by that name 11 years before it was published... @Glen_b , please write an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Glen_b above, what's described in Hamilton's paper is equivalent to `gpava` from the CRAN package `isotone`.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the algorithm, you need to locate positions where `p` is decreasing and, starting from each of these, find out for how long the (cumulative) weighted average is decreasing so that `p` can be updated block by block. I do not see how this can be done without a loop of some sort. Some solution might hide the loop under `lapply` or an equivalent but IMHO, this is one of those algorithms that are complex enough that I prefer a good old loop. You may lose a bit in efficiency but the code reads nicely. My attempt, using a `while` loop:

```
smooth.p <- function(df) {

   while (any(diff(df$p) < 0)) {

      # where does it start decreasing
      idx <- which(diff(df$p) < 0)[1]

      # from there, compute the cumulative weighted average
      sub <- df[idx:nrow(df), ]
      cuml.wavg <- cumsum(sub$n * sub$p) / cumsum(sub$n)

      # and see for how long it is decreasing
      bad.streak.len <- rle(diff(cuml.wavg) <= 0)$lengths[1]

      # these are the indices for the block to average
      block.idx <- seq(from = idx, length = bad.streak.len + 1)

      # compute and apply the average p
      df$p[block.idx] <- sum(df$p[block.idx] * df$n[block.idx]) /
                     sum(df$n[block.idx])
   }
   return(df)
}
```

Here is some data, including a rough patch like you suggested:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:9,
                 n = rep(1, 9),
                 p = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 0.9))
df
#   x n   p
# 1 1 1 0.1
# 2 2 1 0.3
# 3 3 1 0.2
# 4 4 1 0.6
# 5 5 1 0.5
# 6 6 1 0.5
# 7 7 1 0.8
# 8 8 1 1.0
# 9 9 1 0.9
```

And the output:

```
smooth.p(df)
#   x n         p
# 1 1 1 0.1000000
# 2 2 1 0.2500000
# 3 3 1 0.2500000
# 4 4 1 0.5333333
# 5 5 1 0.5333333
# 6 6 1 0.5333333
# 7 7 1 0.8000000
# 8 8 1 0.9500000
# 9 9 1 0.9500000
```

Comment: Interestingly, [the code for PAVA that Glen_b references above](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/isotone/R/gpava.R?root=psychor&view=log) can't avoid using a loop either.